spring gateway in wildfly server
I have an application using Spring Cloud Gateway and a microservice built with Spring Boot. When I run them through IntelliJ, they work perfectly. However, when I deploy them on two local WildFly instances, it can no longer find the routes from the gateway, and I can only access the microservice directly. I'm using WildFly 33 and JDK 21 and Kotlin.
My router
@Configuration
class GatewayConfig(
  @Autowired private val gatewayFilter: GatewayFilter,
) {
  
  @Bean
  fun customRouteLocator(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator {
    return builder.routes().route(
        "chamados"
      ) { r: PredicateSpec ->
        r.path("/api-chamado/api/v1/chamados").filters {
            it.filter(gatewayFilter)
          }.uri("http://localhost:8289")
      }.build()
  }
}

My Filter
@Component
@RefreshScope
class GatewayFilter(
  private val routeValidator: RouteValidator,
  
  ) : GatewayFilter {
  
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange?, chain: GatewayFilterChain?): Mono<Void> {
    val request = exchange!!.request
    /* /api/v1/auth */
    if (routeValidator.isSecured().test(request)) {
      if (request.isAuthMissing()) {
        return onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
      }
      val token = request.headers.getOrEmpty("Authorization")

    }
    return chain!!.filter(exchange)
  }
  
  fun ServerHttpRequest.isAuthMissing() :Boolean {
    return !this.headers.containsKey("Authorization")
  }
  private fun onError(exchange: ServerWebExchange, httpStatus: HttpStatus): Mono<Void> {
    val response = exchange.response
    response.setStatusCode(httpStatus)
    return response.setComplete()
  }
  private fun String.extractTokenValue() : String =
    this.substringAfter("Bearer ")
}

gateway\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml

microservice\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml

gateway application.yml

microservice application.properties

When I call the API directly -> 200 OK

When I call the API through the gateway -> 404 Not Found

wildfly:
**
I have already tried changing the ports and the context-root, but I was not successful.**
